# Missing styles. Is the correct theme chosen for this layout, (can not resolve AppCombatActivity)

Tags: java, android, android-appcompat, main-activity

I need help because i build this project(from udacity course of android beginner)
its ok but when i clean it and reopen it shows an error related to my theme used. Please any help would be appreciated.

[image]

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.android.scorekeeper"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
}
```

Comment: please post ur app/build.gradle

Comment: i am embarrassed to say that i don't know what you are asking to post.

Comment: he is asking for file `build.gradle` which is stored in subfolder `app` in your project directory

Answer (score 0):

Find the below lines in `app/build.gradle` file

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0' // ensure this line is present
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
```

Comment: i found this line    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'